# What does it mean for the set of Co-$H$ structures of Moore space to be in $1-1$ correspondence with Ext $(G, G \otimes G)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, derived-functors

I am trying to understand the following abstract of a paper written by MARTIN ARKOWITZ AND MAREK GOLASINSKI :

[image]

I am building my understanding of co$-H$ structures on the book of Marty Arkowitz named "Introduction to homotopy theory" and my understanding of **EXT** derived functor on Harpreet Bedi homology series lectures which I think depending on the book of Weinbel who is a student of Joseph Rotman.

Could anyone help me in understanding this, please?

Also, Is that question suitable to be send on Math Stack overflow?

Comment: Did you try to read the paper? Since that's the result in the paper, you'll probably find further explanation in it... Here the Ext functor is the usual Ext in abelian groups. Proposition 4 explains the correspondence explicitly.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff thank you! also, I want to understand are those functions $$f: M(G,2) \rightarrow M(H,2)$$ completely laid out in this paper? I attended a seminar and the speaker said that. If so, where they are exactly in the paper?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff do you suggest any other books for reading on co-H spaces and H spaces other than the one of Marty Arkowitz to understand them better?

Comment: I haven't read the paper. Perhaps try to read it a bit more first to get more concrete questions. People may be reluctant to read a paper to explain it to you. :)

Comment: The thing is that there are a lot of things that I do not understand :) @PedroTamaroff

Comment: Then start reading... ;)

Comment: What part of the statement do you not understand?